# Recycler View onBindViewHolder

Tags: android

I make an API call and get a response and store it in an `ArrayList`.
I have 1 `Textview` and 1 `ImageView` to populate.
Now when I get the response it's according to the JSON (i.e in Order)
But when I try to set it in my Adapter it comes as Random (i.e No Order)

Here it is in Order:

```
JSONArray imageArray = imageData.optJSONArray("images");
for (int i = 0; i < imageArray.length(); i++)
{
    JSONObject img = imageArray.optJSONObject(i);
    allID.add(i,img.optString("id"));
    allTitles.add(i,img.optString("title"));
    Log.d("Image ID: ", allID.get(i));
    Log.d("Image Title: ", allTitles.get(i));
    JSONArray imagePath = img.optJSONArray("display_sizes");
    for (int j = 0; j < imagePath.length(); j++)
    {
        JSONObject jb = imagePath.optJSONObject(j);
        allImagePath.add(j, jb.getString("uri"));
        Log.d("Image Path: ", allImagePath.get(j));

    }

    modelGettyImages.setID(allID);
    modelGettyImages.setTitle(allTitles);
    modelGettyImages.setImagePath(allImagePath);
    ImagesList.add(modelGettyImages);

}
```

Now in this Adapter the ImagePath is not according to the order:

```
public class ImageCustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageCustomAdapter.ImagesViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    private ArrayList<ModelGettyImages> images;
    private ArrayList<ModelGettyImages> allImages = new ArrayList<>();

    public ImageCustomAdapter(ArrayList<ModelGettyImages> images,Context context) {
        this.images = images;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ImagesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_row, parent, false);
        ImagesViewHolder imagesViewHolder = new ImagesViewHolder(view);


        return imagesViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ImagesViewHolder holder, int position) {


        List<String> text = images.get(position).getTitle();
        Log.d("TitleAdapter : ",images.get(position).getTitle().toString());
        List<String> image = images.get(position).getImagePath();
        Log.d("ImageAdapter : ", images.get(position).getImagePath().toString());
        holder.title.setText(text.get(position));
        Picasso.with(context).load(image.get(position)).fit().centerCrop().into(holder.image);




    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return images.size();
    }

    public class ImagesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView image;
        TextView title;
        public ImagesViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

             image = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
             title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please share your JSON response?

Answer (score 0):

Parse your response like below,

```
JSONArray imageArray = imageData.optJSONArray("images");
for (int i = 0; i < imageArray.length(); i++)
{
    JSONObject img = imageArray.optJSONObject(i);

    Log.d("Image ID: ", img.optString("id"));
    Log.d("Image Title: ", img.optString("title"));

    JSONArray imagePath = img.optJSONArray("display_sizes");

    for (int j = 0; j < imagePath.length(); j++)
    {
        JSONObject jb = imagePath.optJSONObject(j);
        allImagePath.add(j, jb.getString("uri"));
        Log.d("Image Path: ", allImagePath.get(j));

    }

    modelGettyImages.setId(img.optString("id"));
    modelGettyImages.setTitle(img.optString("title"));
    modelGettyImages.setImagePaths(allImagePath);
    ImagesList.add(modelGettyImages);
}
```

Prepare you model class `ModelGettyImages` with below variables and getters-setters. (I have just mentioning variables in Model class, you need to auto generate getters-setters for those)

```
private String id, title;
private List<String> imagePaths;
```

Update `onBindViewHolder` method as below,

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ImagesViewHolder holder, int position) {

    ModelGettyImages currentImage = images.get(position);

    Log.d("TitleAdapter : ",currentImage.getTitle();
    List<String> imagePaths = currentImage.getImagePaths();

    // Below is the list of images with multiple dimension. 
    // And we are using very first dimension image from that.
    Log.d("ImageAdapter : ", imagePaths.get(0).toString());

    holder.title.setText(currentImage.getTitle());
    Picasso.with(context).load(imagePaths.get(0)).fit().centerCrop().into(holder.image);
}
```